# Advice about using a loop through parameters of a get request

Tags: python, web-scraping, beautifulsoup, request

I am trying to get each runners' information from [this 2017 marathon](http://results-2017.virginmoneylondonmarathon.com/2017/). The problem is that to get the information I want, I would have to click on each runners' name to get his [partial splits](http://results-2017.virginmoneylondonmarathon.com/2017/?pid=list).

I know that I can use a get request to get each runners' information. For example, for the runner [Josh Griffiths](http://results-2017.virginmoneylondonmarathon.com/2017/?content=detail&fpid=list&pid=list&idp=9999990F5ECC85000024C3F9&lang=EN_CAP&event=MAS&search%5Bage_class%5D=%25&search%5Bsex%5D=M&search_event=MAS) I can use `request.get` using the parameters in the url.

My problem is that I don't know how to figure out the `idp` term because this term changes with every runner.

My questions are the following:

1. Is it possible to use a loop to get all runners' information using a get request? How can I solve the issue with the `idp? I mean, the fact that I don't know how this term is determined and I don't know how to define a loop using it.
2. Is there a better method to get each runners' information? I thought about using Selenium-Webdriver, but this would be very slow.

Any advice would be appreciated!

Comment: Links are broken.

Comment: @Tico They work in my browser.

Comment: Well...  now they work..  :/   Weird...   Before there was a broken twitter page. Very weird. Sry about that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You will need to use something like [BeautifulSoup](https://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/#installing-beautiful-soup) to parse the HTML for the links you need, that way there is no need to try and figure out how to construct the request.

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

base_url = "http://results-2017.virginmoneylondonmarathon.com/2017/"
r = requests.get(base_url + "?pid=list")
soup = BeautifulSoup(r.content, "html.parser")
tbody = soup.find('tbody')

for tr in tbody.find_all('tr'):
    for a in tr.find_all('a', href=True, class_=None):
        print
        print a.parent.get_text(strip=True)[1:]
        r_runner = requests.get(base_url + a['href'])
        soup_runner = BeautifulSoup(r_runner.content, "html.parser")

        # Find the start of the splits
        for h2 in soup_runner.find_all('h2'):
            if "Splits" in h2:
                splits_table = h2.find_next('table')

                splits = []
                for tr in splits_table.find_all('tr'):
                    splits.append([td.text for td in tr.find_all('td')])

                for row in splits:
                    print '  {}'.format(', '.join(row))

                break
```

For each link, you then need to follow it and parse splits from the returned HTML. The script will display starting as follows:

```
Boniface, Anna (GBR)

  5K, 10:18:05, 00:17:55, 17:55, 03:35, 16.74, -
  10K, 10:36:23, 00:36:13, 18:18, 03:40, 16.40, -
  15K, 10:54:53, 00:54:44, 18:31, 03:43, 16.21, -
  20K, 11:13:25, 01:13:15, 18:32, 03:43, 16.19, -
  Half, 11:17:31, 01:17:21, 04:07, 03:45, 16.04, -
  25K, 11:32:00, 01:31:50, 14:29, 03:43, 16.18, -
  30K, 11:50:44, 01:50:34, 18:45, 03:45, 16.01, -
  35K, 12:09:34, 02:09:24, 18:51, 03:47, 15.93, -
  40K, 12:28:43, 02:28:33, 19:09, 03:50, 15.67, -
  Finish, 12:37:17, 02:37:07, 08:35, 03:55, 15.37, 1

Griffiths, Josh (GBR)

  5K, 10:15:52, 00:15:48, 15:48, 03:10, 18.99, -
  10K, 10:31:42, 00:31:39, 15:51, 03:11, 18.94, -
  ....
```

To better how understand how this works, you first need to take a look at the HTML source for each of the pages. The idea being is to find something unique about what you are looking for in the structure of the page to allow you to extract it using a script.

Next I would recommend reading through the documentation page for BeautifulSoup. This assumes you understand the basic structure of an HTML document. This library gives you many tools to help you search and extract elements from the HTML. For example finding where the links are. Not all webpages can be parsed like this as the information is often created using Javascript. In these cases you would need to use something like `selenium` but in this case, `requests` and `beautifulsoup` do the job nicely.